# What is the alternative syntax for first and second in ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

```
<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 pad-0 col-hover">
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 pad-10 ">
        <img class="img1"  src="/assets/choose-style/img1.png">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8">
        <h5><%= CaricatureType.first.name %></h5>
        <p class="text-color">
            <%= CaricatureType.first.description %>
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 roundedTwo">
        <input type="radio" value="None" id="roundedTwo" name="check" />
        <label for="roundedTwo"></label>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have a couple of divs like these, but in the above example I am hardcoding **CaricatureType.first.name** like this. But I want to do it in a for loop, if there a syntax in which I can do something like `CaricatureType[0].name`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some ideas. Suppose you want to iterate over all `CaricatureType` records. Then do like

```
<% CaricatureType.all.each do |caricature_type| %>
  <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8">
     <h5><%= caricature_type.name %></h5>
     <p class="text-color">
       <%= caricature_type.description %>
     </p>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Or if you want first 10 records, then:

```
<% CaricatureType.first(10).each do |caricature_type| %>
```

Note: Yeah, it is acceptable not to put any model query inside the view. Keep them in the corresponding action of the controller which rendering the current view/partial, and then use those instance variables in the view. I just wanted to tell you in this answer what is work around of the problem you are facing. So you will store the query result inside `@caricature_types` in your controller action, and then use it to iterate.

Comment: Hey in the first example, are you not getting only first record in the loop?

Comment: you mean to say the block variable has to be like this caricature_type.name? instead of caricature_type.first.name?

Comment: @gates Thanks man. I am bit in problem, so lacking concentration.

Answer (score 3):

Don't write business logic in the views, rather you can use instance variable.

In your controller:

```
@caricature_type = CaricatureType.all
```

then in your view,  you can use this instance variable.

```
<% @caricature_type.each do |caricature_type| %>
   <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8">
      <h5><%= caricature_type.name %></h5>
      <p class="text-color">
         <%= caricature_type.description %>
     </p>
   </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
client = Client.first(numerical value)
```

If numerical value is 2 it will return first 2 records

```
client = Client.first(2)
=> [ <Client id: 1, first_name: "Lifo">, <Client id: 2, first_name: "Fifo">]
```